# Player's inventory look for item

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am stuck looking for a way to test for an item in a player's inventory so far nothing has worked  any help would be nice

Comment: Do you mean placing it, seeing if it is there? please clarify, so that help can be better.

Answer (score 1):

**I did not see the pocket edition tag when I gave this answer.  This answer will not work for pocket edition.  These commands are for Java Edition 1.12.2**

Here is a command to check all player's inventories for a diamond:

```
testfor @a {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond"}]}
```

You can change *minecraft:diamond* to other items/blocks.

If you need to test for a specific amount, you can add count to the command:

```
testfor @a {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:64b}]}
```

This tests for a full stack of 64.

Those commands will go positive if a player has the item(s) but is not very useful otherwise.  You can also add a [scoreboard tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Tags) to the player who has the item(s). This allows you to target the players that have the item in other commands:

```
scoreboard players tag @a add Holding {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:64b}]}
```

Then you can [use that tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_tag) within the [target selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors) of another command.  As an example, lets make everyone who has the diamonds say hello:

```
/execute @a[tag=Holding] ~ ~ ~ say hello
```

Comment: Thank's for your reply.  I have tried this formula. I should have mentioned I'm playing on Minecraft Windows 10.  Any help would be grateful.

Comment: I did not see the pocket edition tag.  I apologize.  Unfortunately, my knowledge is mainly the Java edition of the game.

Answer (score -1):

You could use /invinsee then player name.